# Cookie from backend is not being set when using "dist" (prod) version of project

Tags: angular, express

I have a project with a simple login using Angular and Express. The front end has a simple form with username and password. It then uses http to send a post request.

```
login(data: any) {
    return this.http.post(`${this.baseURL}user/login`, data, { withCredentials: true }).pipe(catchError((err) => { return throwError(() => err) }));
}
```

In the backend (Express) this is what is happening:

```
const { username, password } = req.body;

if(!(username && password)) {
    return res.status(400).send("All input is required");
}

const user = await DBObject.findOne({ 
    where: { username: username },
});

if (user && (await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password))) {
    const token = jwt.sign(
        { userId: user.id },
        process.env.TOKEN_KEY,
        {
            expiresIn: "8h"
        }
    )

    res.cookie('user', token, { maxAge: 8 * 60 * 60 * 1000, secure: process.env.NODE_ENV !== "development" });
    return res.status(200).json();
}
return res.status(400).send("Invalid credentials.")
```

If I run this locally in my computer, it works perfectly. It sets the cookie in the browser and everything. However, when I try a live version, the cookie is never set. I even checked the headers and the set-cookie header is there, but for some reason it is not being set in the browser, which I need it to do. Everything I've read so far says to add the `withCredentials: true` to the http request, but as you can see I am already doing that. Any help with this will be greatly appreciated.

UPDATE: For the record, I did try removing the `secure` option in the `res.cookie` but to no avail.

Comment: In prod, is `this.baseURL` correct?

Comment: Yes, it is taken from an environment variable. The endpoint is being hit, so I don't believe that's the problem. Thank you for your answer!